# In my Perl CGI script, how can I access the checked values in a checkbox group?

Tags: html, arrays, perl, forms, cgi

I have a form with several input methods. I pass that data to a perl script to process print out text based on the data input. I am having a problem with the values of a checkbox group. (checkboxes all with the same name)

```
<td>Profiles: </td>
 <td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"oneconnect\" name=\profile[]\">OneConnect <br />
 <input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"http\" name=\profile[]\">HTTP <br />
 <input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"xforwardedfor\" name=\profile[]\">Xforwarded-for</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

The action sends this data to a perl script for processing.

```
read (STDIN, $FormData, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
@pairs = split(/&/, $FormData);
print Dumper($FormData);

foreach my $pair (@pairs) {
# Separate the name and value:
($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
# Convert + signs to spaces:
$value =~ tr/+/ /;
# Convert hex pairs (%HH) to ASCII characters:
$value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
# Store values in a hash called %FORM:
$FORM{$name} = $value;
}
```

I can then print most of the data the with:

```
print "$FORM{'vsip1'}  $FORM{'vsport1'} <br />\n";
```

However, I cannot access the name "profile" from the checkboxes with the same print command. I do see the "profile" values when I "dump" the data.
print dumper output shows (&%5Cprofile%5B0%5D%22=oneconnect&%5Cprofile%5B1%5D%22=http&SubmitForm) Is this a hash of a hash? and how can I access these values in perl.

Thank you for any suggestions you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [CGI](http://metacpan.org/module/CGI) or [CGI::Simple](http://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aSimple) so you don't have to worry about such matters.

```
my @profile = $cgi->param('profile');
```

See [param](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#FETCHING-THE-VALUE-OR-VALUES-OF-A-SINGLE-NAMED-PARAMETER%3a).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was able to get this working with param.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  That does look like a lot of excess work.  Are you not using a web server?

Pack?  Take a look at [uri_escape](http://www.perlhowto.com/encode_and_decode_url_strings).

As mentioned above, here's a snippet using CGI:

```
<html>
  <form <form name='formName' method='POST' action='someperlscript.pl'>
  <tr><td>
     <input type=checkbox name='XMatch' $xMatch> Exact Match
  </td></tr>
  </form>
</html>

use CGI;

my $q = new CGI;

$xMatch = $q->param( "XMatch" );

$xMatch = ( $xMatch eq "on" ? "checked" : "" );

...
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the above code was written to be tested from the command line. If you create and export an environment variable named CONTENT_LENGTH, and assign it a numeric value at least as long as the string of name-value pairs you are checking, it will dump them as a string (using Dumper), and, if the names correspond to the keys in $FORM{'vsip1'}, $FORM{'vsport1'}, and so forth, it should print them if they are text boxes, or some other HTML widget that always returns a value. If you include an item representing a check box on the command line, it prints it as well, if it includes a value. However, if you are interpreting a query string from an HTML form within a perl CGI handler, it will only include the checkbox name-value pair if the checkbox has been checked. Otherwise, it does not return any of that name-value pair. I tested this on a short HTML page with a CGI processing script, and this was the result.